# Bootstrap 5 navbar - center pills regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My understanding is that I can nest `container-fluid` inside `navbar` and then use the grid. I'm trying to have a navbar have 3 elements: logo left, navigation breadcrumbs center, and then button on the right. I do this with `col` and it looks great in mobile. However, in a bigger screen, it pulls to the left and is messed up, even though all the `cols` add up to 12.

Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/p/jTBpYDfUk9

Here's the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top border border-3 border-danger border-top-0 border-start-0 border-end-0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1">
              <img ...>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-10 tiny-text">
                <nav aria-label="">
                    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center m-0">
                      <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link p-1 px-lg-3 previous_page" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                          <i aria-hidden="true" class="bi-chevron-double-left text-danger"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="page-item active" data-page="0"><a class="page-link p-1 px-lg-3 text-reset disabled pe-none" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">1</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item" data-page="1"><a class="page-link p-1 px-lg-3 text-reset disabled pe-none" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">2</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item" data-page="2"><a class="page-link p-1 px-lg-3 text-reset disabled pe-none" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">3</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item" data-page="3"><a class="page-link p-1 px-lg-3 text-reset disabled pe-none" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">4</a></li>
                      <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link p-1 px-lg-3 next_page" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                          <i aria-hidden="true" class="bi-chevron-double-right text-danger"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 text-end">
                <i class="bi-cart-fill text-danger fs-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#cart-panel" aria-controls="cart-panel"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add one more bootstrap class `w-100` on the 3rd line like this `<div class="row align-items-center w-100">`